# How do I cite a short story if there is only one page?

Tags: citations, essay

How do I cite a short story if there is only one page? Do I just write "example"(1)?

Comment: Do you mean that the story you're citing is only one page, or that the work in which you're citing it is?  Why do you think the length of the story affects the citation?  You can [edit] to add more information to your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Citing depends heavily on the format you're citing it in**. I would highly recommend looking for any citation guidelines for whatever you're writing first, or *ask someone if there is a certain format*. MLA is very commonly accepted.

I would recommend using [Easybib](http://www.easybib.com/).

In regards to your question, it seems fairly vague - however remember that citations are to allow readers to reference more information in relation to your subject matter you're speaking about. That's something that many educational systems fail to emphasize, causing students to assume that it's simply 'just there because.'

As long as you can cite the article well enough that someone can find it if they wanted to search for it, then it should be fine. These tips are assuming you're writing this for an academic article.

Personally, if I was to cite a piece of work I would have:

> "[Quote from text]" (Brode, 2005)

and in the appendix or bibliography have:

> Brode, Douglas. Multiculturalism and the Mouse: Race and Sex in Disney Entertainment. Austin: U of Texas, 2005. Web.

However, you can also do it like this:

> "[Quote from text]" (1.1)
>
> (1.1) England, Dawn Elizabeth, Lara Descartes, and Melissa A. Collier-Meek. "Gender Role Portrayal and the Disney Princesses." Sex Roles 64.7-8 (2011): 555-67. Web.

Or even use footnotes, however, *remember that certain institutions and examiners may have certain restrictions on formatting.* I used MLA formatting for the examples.